# $-x.x$ notation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, notation

I have come across this "$-x.x$" notation in a paper and I'm not sure what it means:

> ... the most simple example on the real line $\frac{dx}{dt} = -x.x$ with initial condition $a$ at $t=0$ has solution $1/(t-1/a)$.

> ... the same calculation works for $\frac{dX}{dt} = -X.X$ where $X$ is a linear operator.

The author specifies in the previous paragraph

> ... the underlying space can be viewed as the (infinite dimensional) vector space $V$ of exact two forms on a closed Riemannian manifold.

This is in the context of Euler equations. Thanks!

Comment: Is the discussion in $n$ dimensions (so that $x.x$ is the dot product of vectors),and he gives as illustration $n=1$ where solution is as stated.

Comment: This would make sense, as the author talks about an infinite dimensional vector space. However, what does it mean in the context of the operator $X$?

Answer (score 1):

It means "the negative of $x$ multiplied with $x$". Other common ways of writing the same is $-x^2$, or $-x\cdot x$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Would it mean the same for the operator $X$?

Comment: @Zarathustra Yes, the dot still means multiplication.